# js files are not loading in django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a little issue with my django project. My static files are loading (img and css) whereas js files are not. I have created a folder static in my app with the following structure `static/js/my_app/` with my js files in it.

Here is the part of my template using js scripts :

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{% static 'js/landing/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/landing/jquery.scrolly.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/landing/jquery.dropotron.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/landing/jquery.scrollex.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/landing/util.js' %}"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="{% static 'js/landing/main.js' %}"></script>
```

And here is the part of my settings.py file dealing with static files :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Thanks

Comment: You have put your files in `static/js/my_app` but are then trying to access them at `js/` directly. You need to change all your `static` calls to start with `js/my_app`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the standard recommendation is to have app_name/static/app_name/js/file.js

Then in template you would just use: {% static 'app_name/js/file_name.js' %}, provided everything else for static is set up correctly.

In your configuration you have done static/js/app_name instead of static/app_name/js.

Comment: Hi BobbyC, thank you for your answer, I did all the changes as you indicated and my js are still not loading! My static folder is now my_app/static/my_app/js/file.js and my call are <script src="{% static 'landing/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

Comment: So, is "landing" your app name ?. If it is, then did you create the file/folder in "landing/static/landing/js/jquery.min.js" ?  Is the app name in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings. You said your css was getting picked up. Can you show the static call you made for the css file and also what path you put the css file at ?

Comment: Yep it is, here is my static call for my css :

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'landing/css/main.css' %}">

Answer (score 0):

if you are follow this steps means you can make direct call call your js or css file /static/css/a.css , in template , make sure the
 collectstatic method

```
import os
def root(x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..',x)
MEDIA_ROOT = root('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = root('staticstorage')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root('static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',

)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    root('templates')
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    "--------------------------------------"
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)

url.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),

) 

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not logical, but if you do it, it might be right
In the same js directory, create another directory called js and transfer your file to it
Run your site now, maybe it has changed
Create another file in the new directory called js and transfer the file to it
Save again and run it
That means, now your file should be in js/js/js/file.js
Now put the file back in the primary directory and run the code, maybe it will be fixed
I said that it doesn't make sense, but I did it and it worked
In addition, you must link the file that you moved correctly in the html file (after changing the path of the js file each time).
I calculated from the js file, but you should calculate from the file that contains your JavaScript code

Answer (score -1):

It could be because of the site's cache, pressing ctrl+f5 might fix it

Comment: This is commentary and not necessarily a solution. More a mere guess that could point into the right direction. A comment should have been used. Note that missing reputations is no excuse to use other options as a workaround to your account limitations.